# Is there any way to prevent the cpu be taken from a process while it is in a handler?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, cpu

I have created a sigaction handler so that when a process receives SIGUSR1 it goes to a function and dies there (there is no possibility that it won't die inside the handler). Is there a way other than using semaphores or mailboxes to prevent the cpu from being taken away from that process while it is in that function and until it dies? I'm on linux (c)

The handler:

```
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler=death;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if(-1==sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL))
    {
        perror("SIGACTION: SIGUSR1");       
    }
```

The death function:

```
    void death()
    {
        //Code
        exit(0); 
        //In this point the cpu can now be taken from this process
    }
```

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? See also http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Im trying to prevent the cpu be taken from a specific process when it enters in de function handler